# python mongoengine EmbeddedDocumentListField and aggregate

Tags: python, mongoengine

I wanna now if MongoEngine `aggregate()` functionality only works on QuerySet?
well, this is the project I'm working on

```
#imports

class Status(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "active"
    CLOSED = "closed"

class OrderType(Enum):
    BUY = "buy"
    SELL = "sell"

class Order(EmbeddedDocument):
    type = EnumField(OrderType, required=True)
    vol = IntField(required=True)
    time = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.now())

class Stock(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField(max_length=20, required=True)
    orders = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Order, required=True)
    status = EnumField(Status, required=True, default=Status.ACTIVE)
    amount = IntField(required=True, default=0)
    pnl = FloatField()

class Portfolio(Document):
    account = IntField(required=True, unique=True)
    stocks = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Stock, required=True)
    balance = FloatField()
    equity = FloatField()
```

I want to be able to make `Stock.amount` field be an aggregation of `Order.vol` which, as can be seen, is an EmbeddedDocumentListField of stock. I already know about mongoengine.signals and seen examples on aggregate(), but all of them use aggregate() on QuerySet returned by `.objects()`. So what is the tweak for it? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I come up with this:

```
def handler(event):
    def decorator(fn):
        def apply(cls):
            event.connect(fn, sender=cls)
            return cls

        fn.apply = apply
        return fn

    return decorator

@handler(signals.post_init)
def update_amount(sender, document):
    orders = document.orders
    amnt = 0
    for order in orders:
        if order.type == OrderType.Buy:
            amnt += order.vol
        else:
            amnt -= order.vol
    document.amount = amnt
```

and then I added decorator `@update_amount.apply` to my `Stock` class. but it would work nicer with aggregate if it's possible

Comment: well, this works when for example i do `stock = Stock(name="AAPL", orders=[Order(type=OrderType.BUY, vol=100.)], pnl=-2.0)`. but i now have the problem when doing something like `Portfolio.objects(account=1, stocks__stock__exact="AAPL").update(push__stocks__S__orders=Order(type=OrderType.BUY,vol=23.0))`. is there any other way to hook the signal to update on orders field of Stock?